# What's wrong with my Taylor -Maclaurin- Series? $e^{x^2+x}$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

Here's what I have:

We know: 
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3 +\frac{1}{4!}x^4$$

Now I can calculate the Taylor Series for $e^{x^2+x}$:

$$1+u+u^2+\frac{1}{2!}(x^2+x)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(x^2+x)^3$$
$$1+u+u^2+\frac{1}{2!}(u^2+2u^3+u^4)$$
$$1+u+u^2+\frac{1}{2!}u^2 +u^3 + \frac{1}{2!}u^4$$
Now for the third degree terms:
$$\frac{1}{3!}(u+u^2)^3$$
$$(u+u^2)(u+u^2)(u+u^2)$$
$$(u+u^2)(u^2+2u^3+u^4)$$
$$\frac{1}{3!}(u^3+2u^4+u^5+u^2+2u^5+u^6)$$
$$\frac{1}{3!}(u^3+2u^4+3u^5+u^6)$$
$$\frac{1}{6}(u^3+2u^4+3u^5+u^6)$$
$$1+u+\frac{3}{2}u^2+u^3+\frac{1}{2}u^4+\frac{1}{6}u^3+\frac{1}{3}u^4+\frac{1}{2}u^5+\frac{1}{6}u^6$$
Which gives us the final result of:

$$1+u+\frac{3}{2}u^2+\frac{7}{6}u^3+\frac{5}{6}u^4$$
The last term is wrong. It should be $\frac{25}{24}u$ but I don't now why my answer is wrong.

You help is highly appreciated,

Cro-Magnon

Comment: Your expansion of $(u+u^2)^3$ is wrong - note that it's the same as $u^3(1+u)^3=u^3(1+3u+3u^2+u^3)$, and your coefficients don't match. Also note that if you want accuracy up to the $u^4$ term, you're going to need to expand the $(u+u^2)^4$  term from the $e^{u+u^2}$ term as well.

Comment: As a side note, it may be easier to multiply $e^x+O(x^5)$ times $e^{x^2}+O(x^5)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally:

$$\exp{(u+u^2)}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(u+u^2)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{u^n(1+u)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{0\le k \le n}\frac{u^{n+k}}{n!}\binom{n}{k}$$

So, the coefficient of $u^m$ will be:

$$\sum_{n+k=m}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n!}=\sum_{0\le k\le\frac{m}{2}}\frac{1}{k!(m-2k)!}$$

For example:

- $\frac{1}{0!0!}=1$ is the constant coefficient
- $\frac{1}{0!1!}=1$ is the coefficient of $u$
- $\frac{1}{0!2!}+\frac{1}{1!0!}=\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{3}{2}$ is the coefficient of $u^2$
- $\frac{1}{0!3!}+\frac{1}{1!1!}=\frac{1}{6}+1=\frac{7}{6}$ is the coefficient of $u^3$
- $\frac{1}{0!4!}+\frac{1}{1!2!}+\frac{1}{2!0!}=\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{25}{24}$ is the coefficient of $u^3$

and so on.

There are other ways of developing the coefficients for series like this. One common alternative approach (particularly for functions involving exponentials) is to note that if $f(u)=\exp(u+u^2)$, then $\frac{df}{du}=(1+2u)f$, and then comparing the power series of both sides.

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting the contribution from the fourth degree terms (in the original series):
$$\frac{1}{4!}(u+u^2)^4 = \frac{1}{24}\left(u^4 + \mbox{higher order terms} \right)$$
You also made a small mistake in the expansion of the third order term, the contribution in $u^4$ has coefficient $1/2$ (contribution: $(3u^4)/3!=u^4/2$ + other order terms) instead of $1/3$, yielding a total of $1/2+1/2+1/24 = 25/24$.

Comment: Where does the coefficient $1/2$ from $u^4$ come from?

Comment: The first 1/2 comes from the second order term (you found that), the second one comes from the third order term (you made a mistake, see my answer for the contribution to $u^4$ from that term).